# Angular Material reactive forms, updating mat-select options based on other select

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I'm currently creating a dashboard in Angular 6, Material 2. (versions listed below)

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.9",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.37",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  }
```

I've created a form where a user can select data to include in a report to be generated.

I have all bound the controls using reactive forms. The problem lies with two `mat-select` elements, the second element's options depend on the value of the first select.

I.e.

If `select1.value === a` then `select2` will have options `a_1`, `a_2`, etc.

If `select1.value === b` then `select2` will have options `b_1`, `b_2`, etc. etc.

The values of `select2` are bound in the HTML template using

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of dataSourceSelect.value?.units" [value]="item">{{item.toHTMLString()}}</mat-option>
```

When the value of `select1` is changed through the UI, all works as expected. The issue I'm having is when I update a `mat-select`'s value using the `FormControl.setValue(obj)` function. I can update the selected value of `select1` just fine, but the value of `select2` wont be set, the options wont be loaded based on the value of `select1` either.

After searching for similar cases, I suspected the comparator of the mat-select to be the cause, but after passing the original object into `.setValue()` or overriding the `compareWith` function of the `mat-select` it still did not work, so I'm wondering if anyone can help me out here.

I've included minimal reproduction code in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8wwl2)

in the stackblitz: change the value of the first select, you will see that the options of the second select will change, then click the button, which uses `FormControl.setValue(obj)` to set the value of the first select, then the second select wont have any options at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My way I have use `valueChanges` property of dataSourceControl control and work as expected

component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.reportForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      dataSourceControl: ['', Validators.required],
      dataUnitControl: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.reportForm.get('dataSourceControl').valueChanges.subscribe(item => {
      this.units = item.units
    })
```

*template*

```
<mat-form-field>
  <label for="dataUnitSelect">Data unit: </label>
  <mat-select formControlName="dataUnitControl" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of units" [value]="item">{{item.toHTMLString()}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="reportForm.controls['dataUnitControl'].hasError('required')">Please choose a unit</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqenle)

> **valueChages** method return an observable that emits the latest
>   values. You can therefore subscribe to valueChanges to update instance
>   variables or perform operations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was able to implement the desired behaviour using the observable. thank you for your help :)